# I'm having issues with my divs and CSS code

Tags: html, css

I need help with padding and divs.  Everything looks right and has no errors.  What is the problem with my code?

I tried redoing it and nothing works.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* Global styles
---------------------------*/
body
{
    color: #4B88A2;
    margin: 0;
    padding0: 0;
}

img
{
    width: 300px;
}

a
{
    color:#fff66d;
}

a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.content-wrap
{
    width : 900px;
    magrin: 0 auto;
}

/* Profile
---------------------------------*/
header
{
    background: #4B88A2;
    color: #FFF9FB;
}


/* Projects
-------------------------------*/

.projects
{
    background: #BB0A21;
}

.projects a
{
    color: #FFF9FB;
}

.projects .btn
{
    color: #D3D4D9;
    background: #4B88A2;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius:  4px;
}

.projects .btn:hover
{
    background: rgba(75, 136, 162, 80%);
}

/* Work Experience
-------------------------------*/
.work-experience
{
    background-color: #252627;
}

/* Education
-------------------------------*/
.education
{
    background-color: #D3D4D9;
}

/* Contact Info
-----------------------------*/

footer
{
    background: #252627;
    color: #FFF9FB;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Larry's Resume </title>
    <link href="../CSS/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <main>
      <!-- ***********************  ABOUT / PROFILE  *********************** -->
      <header>
        <div class="content-wrap">
          <h1>Larry Joyner</h1>
          <h2>Front End developer/ boot strap developer </h2>

          <p>I'm in the  process of re learning CSS  and Bootstrap .</p>
          <p> I also like doing graphic arts as well.</p>
        </div>
      </header>

      <!-- ********************  PROJECTS / PORTFOLIO  ********************* -->
      <section class="projects">
        <div class="content-wrap">
          <h2>Featured Projects</h2>
          <p>View selected projects below. More information can be found at <a  href="https://www.facebook.com/atum.cloth">Larry Joyner</a></p>

          <!-- Copy the whole <section> block to add more projects. -->
          <section>
            <h3>Demo site</h3>
              <img src="placeholder images/thumbnail-1.jpg" width="320" height="261" alt="panda "/>
              <p>Summary or description of the project and/or your role in it. Add as many paragraphs as you need.</p>
              <a  class="btn" href="#" target="_blank">Case study</a>
          </section>
          <!-- End of Project block. -->
        </div>
      </section>

      <!-- ***********************  WORK EXPERIENCE  *********************** -->
      <section class="work-experience">
        <div class ="content-wrap">
          <h2>Retail </h2>
          <p>I work all over the  store .</p>

          <!-- Copy this whole <section> block to add more jobs. -->
          <section>
            <h3> Eletric associate </h3>
            <p>Home Depot </p>
            <p>Date at job</p>
            <p>Job summary goes here. Add as many paragraphs as you need.</p>
            <p>Optional list:</p>

          </section>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Job block. -->
      </section>

      <!-- ******************  EDUCATION & CERTIFICATIONS ****************** -->
      <section class ="education">
        <div class="content-wrap">
          <h2>Education</h2>

          <!-- Copy this whole <section> block to add more schools. -->
          <section>
            <h3>PGCC  ,Largo MD</h3>
            <p>Designation received or program name, year attended</p>
            <p>Summary or accomplishments.</p>
          </section>
        </div>
        <!-- End of School block. -->
      </section>

      <!-- *****************  CONTACT INFO / SOCIAL MEDIA  ***************** -->
      <footer>
        <div class="content-wrap">
          <h2>Let's Keep in Touch!</h2>

          <!-- Social media and contact links. Add or remove any networks. -->
          <ul>
            <li> <a href="mailto:email@example.com">email@example.com</a></li>
            <li><a  href="http://yourwebsite.com" target="_blank">yourwebsite.com</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a   href="#" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

The content wrapper *div* doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you're expecting the content to look like? "It doesn't work" is a little too vague.

Comment: I'm trying to get the padding and margin to work right. It doesn't show up in my work.

Comment: use a spellchecker or validation service, you have typos in your code: ` magrin: 0 auto;` this is not valid. so your statement `Everything looks right and has no errors` is false. What do you want to achieve exactly? `Does not work` is not a good description. Describe what you expect to work. And how it should work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `section {padding: 15px;"}` to your CSS.

Comment: That didn't work.

Comment: @LarryJoyner If it didn't work, why did you accept it?